# Using reflection in C# to try and access My.Resources

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, reflection

I have inherited a large project written in a mixture of C# and VB.Net

The project involves many separate assemblies.

There are hundreds (or thousands) of resources (png files) that have been inserted into the project using the VB My.Resources functionality that I would like to access from some C# code, in a different assembly.

Microsoft has a [KB article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984408%28VS.71%29.aspx) about this. It includes some sample code, but I  can't get it to work (and I can't quite follow the code).

```
// Gets a reference to the same assembly that 
// contains the type that is creating the ResourceManager.
System.Reflection.Assembly myAssembly;
myAssembly = this.GetType().Assembly;

// Gets a reference to a different assembly.
System.Reflection.Assembly myOtherAssembly;
myOtherAssembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.Load("ResourceAssembly");

// Creates the ResourceManager.
System.Resources.ResourceManager myManager = new 
    System.Resources.ResourceManager("ResourceNamespace.myResources", myAssembly);

// Retrieves String and Image resources.
System.String myString;
System.Drawing.Image myImage;
myString = myManager.GetString("StringResource");
myImage = (System.Drawing.Image)myManager.GetObject("ImageResource");
```

I can't follow why the code creates **myAssembly** and **myOtherAssembly** and never seems to use the second object?

Does the action of loading the second assembly...

```
myOtherAssembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.Load("ResourceAssembly");
```

...mean I don't need to reference it further down when I create a **ResourceManager** ?

```
System.Resources.ResourceManager myManager = new 
    System.Resources.ResourceManager("ResourceNamespace.myResources", myAssembly);
```

Any idea how I can access these resources (with or without reflection) would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Just to clarify, you have lots of .resource files within various assemblies within this solution or do you have lots of png files that have a build action of 'Embedded Resource'?

Answer (score 0):

Try this sample

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yfsz7ac5.aspx

You're right when you say loading myOtherAssembly means you don't have to reference it later. You don't really need to declare a local variable to do it though.

I'm not sure why it wouldn't work. Are you sure the resource namespace is correct? If you add a breakpoint after the ResourceManager is instantiated, can you see any resources in it in the debugger?